# How do I troubleshoot "wrong number of arguments" in solidus affirm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, solidus

Struggling to get solidus_affirm working and hoping anyone might have some ideas. I always have trouble with "wrong number of arguments" errors like this.

Can get through checkout all the way to the confirm step, where it throws a 500.

```
ArgumentError in Spree::CheckoutController#update
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Extracted source (around line #28):

    def post(path, **data)
      connection.post(normalized_path(path), data)
    end

affirm-ruby (1.1.2) lib/affirm/client.rb:28:in 'post'
affirm-ruby (1.1.2) lib/affirm/client.rb:10:in 'public_send'
affirm-ruby (1.1.2) lib/affirm/client.rb:10:in 'request'
affirm-ruby (1.1.2) lib/affirm/charge.rb:7:in 'authorize'
solidus_affirm (4f8d9ee63345) lib/solidus_affirm/affirm_client.rb:18:in 'authorize'
solidus_core (3.1.5) app/models/spree/payment_method.rb:40:in 'authorize'
```

if I put a binding.pry in lib/affirm/charge.rb:7:in 'authorize' of the affirm gem, and try the respond Client.request method there, I get a faraday deprecation warning, not sure if that's the cause or unrelated. Seems like it's injecting an auth header or something?

```
pry(Affirm::Charge)> respond Client.request(:post, "charges", checkout_token: token)
WARNING: 'Faraday::Connection#basic_auth' is deprecated; it will be removed in version 2.0.
While initializing your connection, use '#request(:basic_auth, ...)' instead.
See https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/middleware/authentication for more usage info.
```

In that same binding.pry, I tried a few things to see what came back:

```
[2] pry(Affirm::Charge)> respond Client.request(:post)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

pry(Affirm::Charge)> respond Client.request(:post, "charges")
WARNING: 'Faraday::Connection#basic_auth' is deprecated; it will be removed in version 2.0.
While initializing your connection, use '#request(:basic_auth, ...)' instead.
See https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/middleware/authentication for more usage info.
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Any help troubleshooting the error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error was caused by a change in the behavior of the double splat operator in Ruby 3 and needs to be fixed in the affirm-ruby gem. I submitted a PR and overrode the methods in an initializer.

> In Ruby 3.0, positional arguments and keyword arguments will be separated.
> Ruby 2.7 will warn for behaviors that will change in Ruby 3.0. If you
> see the following warnings, you need to update your code:
>
> Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated, or
> Passing the keyword argument as the last hash parameter is deprecated,
> or Splitting the last argument into positional and keyword parameters
> is deprecated In most cases, you can avoid the incompatibility by
> adding the double splat operator. It explicitly specifies passing
> keyword arguments instead of a Hash object. Likewise, you may add
> braces {} to explicitly pass a Hash object, instead of keyword
> arguments.

Source: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

The splat operator was breaking things: `request(method, path, **data)`

I created an initializer at `config/initializers/affirm-ruby.rb` to override the gem's methods in our Solidus app.

```
module Affirm
  class Client
    class << self
      def request(method, path, data={})
        new.public_send(method, path, data)
      end
    end

    def get(path, data={})
      connection.get(normalized_path(path), data)
    end

    def post(path, data={})
      connection.post(normalized_path(path), data)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the call to `request()` is ambiguous.

```
respond Client.request(:post, "charges", checkout_token: token)
```

Looking at [the source for the `request()` method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/affirm-ruby/1.1.1/Affirm%2FClient.request), it takes two specific positional arguments, followed by any number of positional arguments. That's the problem: it only takes positional arguments. Your call includes a keyword argument of `checkout_token`, but the `request()` method doesn't know what that is, because there's no `checkout_token` keyword parameter on the method definition.

If you need to give a method a hash, you should give it exactly that, just like the article you linked suggests:

```
respond Client.request(:post, "charges", { checkout_token: token })
```